# Finding the exact value of a gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

There are two parts to this question.

Find $\Gamma(\frac{5}{2})$

Use the first part and the pdf of the gamma distribution to find the exact value of $\int_0^\infty x^{1.5}e^{-4x}dx$

I believe I solved the first part correctly, but I'm not sure about the second. I've tried to get it to resemble the pdf of the gamma distribution,

$f(x) = \frac{\lambda^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}$

but there's no integral involved in the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{1.5} e^{-4x} \, dx &=& \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{3/2} e^{-4x} \, dx\\
\\
&=& \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{5/2-1} e^{-4x} \, dx\\
\\
&=& \frac{\Gamma(5/2)}{4^{5/2}} \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(5/2)} \, 4^{5/2} \, x^{5/2-1} e^{-4x} \, dx}_{\mbox{integral of $\Gamma(5/2,1)$ pdf}}\\
\\
&=& \frac{\Gamma(5/2)}{4^{5/2}} 
\end{array}
$$
since the integral of the pdf is $1$.